# Gtk file manager to open as top window

Tags: c, gtk3, file-manager

I have a GTK application where I need to allow the user to open a file manager to delete older data files. I have successfully incorporated this using this bit of code:

```
GError *error = NULL;
if (!g_app_info_launch_default_for_uri ("file:///", NULL, &error)) {
    g_warning ("Failed to open uri: %s", error->message);}
```

This brings up the file manager, but it is beneath my gtk application. Is there a way to put the file manager on top?

Comment: Maybe as alternative consider GtkFileChooserDialog in your app? It should allow deleting files through that one and you have full control over the window.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch, put that as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe as alternative consider GtkFileChooserDialog in your app? It should allow deleting files through that one and you have full control over the window.